# Remote Invoke-Command Issue

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I have an issue with `Invoke-Command` which make me crazy ..

I try to get the last 5 digits of Windows servers licence key , to do that I use this command :

`cscript C:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs /dli`

This command work on all my servers ( when i run it as local ) , but when I send it using `Invoke-Commmand`:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {cscript C:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs /dli}
```

Many servers don't answer me, I just have no PowerShell answer, no output!

Somebody have an idea ?

Comment: Could be WinRM service is not running on the servers or port is being blocked somewhere?  [HOW TO CONFIGURE YOUR COMPUTER FOR REMOTING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_requirements?view=powershell-7.1#how-to-configure-your-computer-for-remoting)

Comment: Also, once remoting is working you can also use WMI and do something like this instead of invoke-command `Get-WmiObject -Class SoftwareLicensingService -ComputerName $server | Select-Object PSComputerName, @{name = 'OA3xOriginalProductKey'; expression = {$_.OA3xOriginalProductKey.substring($_.OA3xOriginalProductKey.length - 5)} }`

Comment: Thanks for you answer , WinRm is working , I request product id and it's work , for the .OA3xOriginalProductKey , it's not working , it give me blank answer on all my servers